# Is there a way to disable SSL verification on wso2 api manager gateway while calling backend api

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am getting SSL errors whenever SSL certificates on backend are updated. Is there a way to disable the SSL verification  in wso2 api manager gateway

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to disable SSL verification for an HTTPS endpoint. It is mandatory to import the backend certificate to the client-trustore file. It is better to use an HTTP endpoint instead of an HTTPS endpoint in these kinds of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks Arunan Sugunakumar. So you mean we can not disable ssl verification by any mean while using wso2 api manager gateway. Actually what I observed is in case the ssl certificates get renewed due to one reason or other, the api manager which was working fine, suddenly starts giving SSL errors. I was curious to know if there is some workaround for this condition and API Manager automatically picks up new certificates may be from some external folder?